# Customize the From address in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have mailer action in my application, the mailer is configured with gmail smtp. The following is my config details under environment.rb file

```
require "smtp_tls"
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true
ActionMailer::Base.default_charset = "utf-8"
ActionMailer::Base.default_content_type = "text/html"

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
:address => "smtp.gmail.com",
:port => 587,
:domain => 'gmail.com',
:user_name => "info@example.com",
:password => "password",
:authentication => :plain
```

The think i want to implement is, when ever the application generating email the from address shows "info@example.com".

Is possible to customize the from address. In different places i want to use different From address instead of "info@example.com"

I tried with my mailer model:

```
@from = "#{user.email}"
```

In development server log it shows the  customized id correctly. if go my email inbox it shows the from address as "info@example.com"

Can any one please guide on this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not `@from`. It's the method `from`.

```
def my_email_sender_method

    from "nobody <noreply@example.com>"
end
```

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your Rely. Is it possible to change <noreply@example.com> into <#{user.email}>. In that place

Comment: Of course. You can set whatever you want plain string or vars.